# attr is not applying in chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

i have created a row an i am applying a attribute in td colspan .copspan is not applying

**my code is like this**

**FooodJournalis my row id**

```
 var newRow = $('#FooodJournal').clone();

  $(newRow).find('td[id^=FooodJournalTd').attr('colspan',6);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are cloning an element, you need to append it to the DOM. Look at appendTo: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try newRow.find instead of $(newRow)? Also, does this work in other browsers?